# Why is the starry night sky so unaturally bright?

Tags: astrophotography, light-pollution

The night sky in my vicinity has been rather poor in stars even when it was (presumably) clear of clouds:

[image: night sky at Oldenburg, Lower Saxony, on 2022-10-02 at 23:00]

You can see an slight orange glow, which hides faint objects in the sky. Here is a [full-size version of this picture](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Akn6ugiGHXH6aYyd9) and an [annotated version.](https://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/6545928#annotated)

Parameters:

- Canon EOS 70D (astromod.) + Canon EF 24–105 mm IS f/4 L
- ISO 1600
- f/4
- 8"
- 54 mm
- 2022-10-02 23:00

Location: [Sandkrug (near Oldenburg), Germany](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/165030708)

Direction: W

Here is the corresponding star chart:

[image: star chart Oldenburg, Lower Saxony, on 2022-10-02 at 23:00]

Where does this mysterious "glow" come from? Cirrostratus clouds? Aerosols? Light pollution? I've got a small town in western direction, but some 3 years ago I didn't observe such heavy light pollution.

Comment: It *looks* like light pollution to me but without knowing where this shot was taken, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Perhaps the small town has a lighted industrial park which wasn't there three years ago, or a floodlit sports pitch with a game in play. Or perhaps they replaced the street lights with a more polluting kind.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Location added.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Lightpollutionmap.info](https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/#zoom=10.00&lat=53.0641&lon=8.2276&layers=B0FFFFFFFTFFFFFFFFFFF), it looks like you are in a fairly polluted area, described as *Rural/suburban transition* (class 4 on the [Bortle Dark Sky Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale)) where

- light pollution domes are visible in several directions
- the Milky Way well above the horizon is still impressive, but lacks detail
- surroundings are clearly visible, even at a distance

According to your own statements, you said you *didn't observe such heavy light pollution some 3 years ago* but it might well be that

- some new light sources might have been added during that 3 years span
- some bright light sources were on during the night when you shot the picture you shared (sports venue / stadium lights / etc.)

You could try to observe the sky for several nights and/or at different times and see whether there are nights or times during which the sky gets darker. And if not, you will probably need to find a better (darker) place in your vicinity, if available, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So it's really increasing light pollution, which makes my night sky so ugly, right? Maybe it's got something to do with the large-scale replacement of gas discharge street lighting with LEDs.

Comment: @Neppomuk worth a read https://physicsworld.com/a/led-streetlights-are-increasing-blue-light-pollution-in-europe/